# New install on new build not loading?

Tags: boot

I installed 16.04 64x using a disc on my new build. It went through all the splash screens then said it needed to restart - so I allowed it to. Then it boots back up and brings me to the menu option of "Install, Try without installing etc" which was the menu I first got when putting the disc in prior to install. I had to leave for work before I could troubleshoot further...Do I need to remove the disc before I can start the OS normally or is there an issue with the install itself?

Answer (score 0):

When the installation is completed, you must remove the disc when prompted.

Eject the disc and reboot the PC.

Comment: I let it restart without removing the disc. Can I just hit F2 when I turn on the pc then eject the disc and try to boot again?